# Business Objects History

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Is it possible to add an instance name to the history of Business Objects?

I want to see the following columns: Time, Instance Name, Run by, Parameters, Format, Status, Reschedule, Selected

[image]

Comment: Anything is possible, but the degree of difficulty is highly variable. What system are you talking about?

Comment: The Business Objects report history on the web GUI.

Comment: I've the same question too. If you found the answer, please update here.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do u mean giving names to the scheduled instances ? You can schedule a report to run and rename it as you wish. I think you should probably look into the Report Scheduler API in the .NET or JAVA SDK provided by SAP. You should be able to add the above mentioned columns also.